XML namespaces in CSS attr()
I can use XML namespaces on CSS attribute selectors fine, even with pseudoclasses:
<root xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace">
    <s xml:id="s382.11.1" n="someValue">Content goes here</s>
</root>

@namespace url(http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0);
@namespace xml url(http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace);
[xml|id]::before {
    content: attr(n);
}

But when applying the same namespace syntax to the attr function in a content declaration, Google Chrome 126 and Opera 106 don't get it, although Firefox 128 does:
@namespace url(http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0);
@namespace xml url(http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace);

s {
    display: block;
    margin: 8px 16px;
    clear: both;
}

s::before {
    content: attr(xml|id);
    display: block;
    float:left;
    width: 144px;
}

Chrome and Opera don't display the ::before pseudoelement at all, i.e. don't reserve the specified width either, unless I set it to a default-namespace attribute @n, in which case they behave as intended. Firefox works as intended with either attribute selected. The W3C CSS Validation Service throws a parse error at precisely this point: xml|id) (sic). It is happy if I write attr(xml\:id) instead, but then no browser renders the pseudoelement. Is there some other way I can render this value? Moving the attribute to the default namespace in my XML corpus is not an option.

Although the basic form of attr() has been around since CSS 2, that only expects its parameter to be an ident, which would make attr(xml|id) invalid. The delta spec draft - CSS Values and Units Level 5 - describes a much more capable attr() which defines that attr(xml|id) should work as you intend, but almost all of that remains unimplemented anywhere. It's no more than a quirk of Firefox that attr(xml|id) does work there. I always hesitate to answer "not possible" to an SO question, but I think that's likely.
